# keyreader: How to save choice key value to a macro

Tags: key-value

Why does a `choice` key not save it’s value to a macro as a `cmd` key and as the corresponding `xkeyval` `\define@choicekey` do?

In the following example I have to define `my@key` manually by using the callback.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keyreader}

\krddefinekeys*{CL}[my]{%
   choice/keya/one/
      one,two,three/\def\mykeya{#1};
   choice/keyb/aa/
      aa,bb,cc,dd;
}

\begin{document}
\mykeya% works
and
%\mykeyb% doesn't work
\end{document}
```

---

With `xkeyval` it is possible to define a `bin` i.e. a macro that saves the value:

```
\define@choicekey*{CL}{keyc}[\mybin]{alpha,beta,gamma,epsilon}[alpha]{}
```

an later `\mybin` holds the value of `keyc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `\define@choicekey` of the *xkeyval* package doesn't yield a macro of the form `\<macro-prefix>@<key-name>` to hold the user input. The command `\krddefinekeys` of the *keyreader* package uses *xkeyval*'s `\define@choicekey` in the background.

The feature you're asking for is available only in the *ltxkeys* package. Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltxkeys}
\makeatletter
\ltxkeys@declarekeys*{fam}[my]{%
% choice/<key name>.{<alternate values>}/<default>/<callback>;
  choice/keya.{one,two,three}/one;
  choice/keyb.{aa,bb,cc,dd}/aa;
% cmd/<key name>/<default>/<callback>;
  cmd/keyc/cc/\def\xc##1{##1xx#1};
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mykeya, \mykeyb\space and \mykeyc
\end{document}
```

Comment: But I can define a `bin` to save the value, please see my edit. Thath’s what I meant but had it wrong in my mind O:-)

Comment: Yes, you can define two bins `\bina` (to hold current user value) and `\binb` (to hold the numerical order of the user input, starting from 0). Your `\mybin` is well placed. NOTE: It is advisable to always provide a key prefix (eg, `[TOB]`) and a family (eg, `{tobi}`).

Comment: OK. But I can’t define a bin with `\krddefinekeys` right?. Why is it better to define a prefix? And why it this argument optional, though?

Comment: I have uploaded onto CTAN a version of keyreader package that allows macro prefixes to be used in `\krddefinekeys` for choice keys (like it has always been for command keys). It will take perhaps 24 hours before the upload is propagated to mirror sites. So for a choice key `keya`, you can now have `\mykeya` as you wanted. Note: Providing both key prefix and family makes your keys unique and reduces the chances of name clashes within and between packages. The default value of key prefix is often KV.

Comment: Thanks for the upload! I’ll do my update tomorrow. But if I define a `<mpprefix>` (`\my`) in my example the prefix isn’t uses anywhere, is it?

Comment: @Tobi: What do you mean by 'isn't used anywhere'? After the upgrade, your example above should work for `\mykeya` and `\mykeyb`. You won't need to define `\def\mykeya{#1}` yourself.

Comment: In my understanding of the prefix it is used do define the macros saving the value, e.g. `\cmdKV@keya`. But if I define the mprefix it’s `\mykeya` so the prefix isn’t used and for that can’t help to avoid conflicts …

Comment: @Tobi: If you define your own macro prefix (`my` as in your example above), then `\cmd<keyprefix>@<family>@<keyname>` will not be formed and used internally. You can avoid name clash by choosing a unique macro prefix (say, `tobi@mypkg@`). Another point: in the `\krddefinekeys` command, the bins for choice keys are always `\krduserinput` and `\krdorder`. You can access these bins in the callback but you will hardly need them. This is because the alternative actions, for which the bins were invented by the author of xkeyval package, are already specified within `\krddefinekeys` by `.do=`.

Comment: OK, thanks! So in my case, i.e. macro prefix is unique, the prefix isn’t necessary?

Comment: I think by 'the prefix isn’t necessary' you're referring to the key prefix and not the macro prefix. Both are not necessary but both are useful. The key prefix is used to define the key macro, normally of the form `\<keyprefix>@<family>@<keyname>`. Here when both `<keyprefix>` and `<family>` are present, they make it less likely that two keys by different authors will have the same key macro, even if they had the same family. If you use only `<family>` and no `<keyprefix>`, then an existing family might easily be overwritten.

Comment: The starred variant of `\krddefinekeys` will raise an error when an existing key is being redefined. So if you must not give `<keyprefix>`, you should consider using the starred variant of `\krddefinekeys` always.