# Can I refer to key value in general code?

Tags: latex3, expl3, key-value

> Related: *[keyreader: How to save choice key value to a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46713/2966)*.

I’m using [`l3keys2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/l3keys2e), but I suspect this might not be the ideal way to go about what I’m trying to do.

I’m building a private package with various tweaks to font setups:

```
\bool_if:nTF { \xetex_if_engine_p: || \luatex_if_engine_p: }
  { \clist_const:Nn \c_jcsfonts_clist { lmodern, fontin, constantia } }
  { \clist_const:Nn \c_jcsfonts_clist { cmodern, kpfonts } }
```

I’m trying to set things up so `\usepackage[font = choice]{jcsfonts}` will enable the correct batch of customizations, with the first entry in the list being the default. This doesn’t seem to work:

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \quark_new:N {c}
\clist_map_inline:Nn \c_jcsfonts_clist { \quark_new:c { q_jcsfonts_ #1 } }

\keys_define:nn { jcsfonts }
  {
    font .choice_code:n =
      { \cs_set_eq:Nc \q_jcsfonts { q_jcsfonts \tl_use:N \l_keys_choice_tl } } ,
    font .generate_choices:n = { \clist_use:Nnnn \c_jcsfonts_clist {,} {,} {,} } ,
  }

\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \jcsfonts_if:n #1 { p, T, F, TF }
  {
    \cs_if_eq:NcTF \q_jcsfonts { q_jcsfonts_ #1 }
      { \prg_return_true: } { \prg_return_false: }
  }

\ProcessKeysOptions { jcsfonts }
```

What is the preferred way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding what you are trying to achieve, but here is a simple way to associate code to various possible values of a key.  The `\keys_define:nn` construction defines the key `font` of module `jcsfonts` to be a "choice" key, which means that the value given for `font` decides what code is performed.  There are two ways of defining the code for each possible choice: either by introducing keys `font/choice-a`, `font/choice-b`, etc, as I do here, or (with a version of expl3 perhaps newer than August 2013 —that's the future) using `.choices:nn`, which defines several choices in one go, with the same code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3, xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { jcsfonts }
  {
    font .choice: ,
    font / lmodern .code:n = { \RequirePackage{lmodern} } ,
    font / kpfonts .code:n = { \RequirePackage{kpfonts} } ,
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \JcsSetup } { m }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { jcsfonts }
      { font = {#1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\JcsSetup{kpfonts}
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

If you want the set of choices to depend on the engine, simply do something like

```
\keys_define:nn { jcsfonts } { font .choice: }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \jcs_fonts_new:nnnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    \pdftex_if_engine:T { \keys_define:nn { jcsfonts } { font / #1 = {#2} } }
    \xetex_if_engine:T  { \keys_define:nn { jcsfonts } { font / #1 = {#3} } }
    \luatex_if_engine:T { \keys_define:nn { jcsfonts } { font / #1 = {#4} } }
  }
\msg_new:nnn { jcsfonts } { font-bad-engine }
  { Cannot~use~font~'#1'~in~engine~'#2'. }
\jcs_fonts_new:nnnn { kpfonts }
  { \RequirePackage{kpfonts} } % code for pdfTeX
  { \RequirePackage{kpfonts} } % code for XeTeX
  {
    \msg_error:nnnn { jcsfonts } { font-bad-engine }
      { kpfonts } { LuaTeX }
  } % code for LuaTeX... that font works, but I needed an example
```

If you more generally want to associate some code to a string among some choice of strings, I would use a property list:

```
\prop_new:N \g__jcs_fonts_code_prop
\prop_gput:Nnn \g__jcs_fonts_code_prop
  { kpfonts }
  { RequirePackage{kpfonts} }
% ...
\tl_new:N \l__jcs_fonts_code_tl
\keys_define:nn { jcsfonts }
  {
    font .code:n =
      {
        \prop_get:NnNTF
          \g__jcs_fonts_code_prop {#1} \l__jcs_fonts_code_tl
          { \tl_use:N \l_jcs_fonts_code_tl }
          { \msg_error:nnn { jcsfonts } { cannot-use-font } {#1} }
      }
  }
\msg_new:nnn { jcsfonts } { cannot-use-font }
  { Cannot~use~font~'#1'. }
```

Once more, you can make the list of fonts depend on the engine by filling the property list differently according to the engine used.

Comment: It appears that `\keys_define:nn { font / unknown .code:n = { <Recovery~code~receiving~unknown~choice~as~#1.> } }` works to recover from unknown choices for a `.choice:` key.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about your usage of quarks; if you want to generate choice keys based on the value of the constant clist defined at startup, you can stretch a bit the available tools and define a `.generate_choice:V` property:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \g_jcs_fonts_font_tl

\bool_if:nTF { \xetex_if_engine_p: || \luatex_if_engine_p: }
 { \clist_const:Nn \c_jcsfonts_clist { lmodern, fontin, constantia } }
 { \clist_const:Nn \c_jcsfonts_clist { lmodern, kpfonts } }

%%% The property .generate_choice:V doesn't exist, so we create it
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__keys_choices_generate:n { V }
\cs_new_protected:cpn { \c__keys_props_root_tl .generate_choices:V } #1
  { \__keys_choices_generate:V {#1} }

\keys_define:nn { jcsfonts }
 {
  font .choice_code:n = \tl_gset:NV \g_jcsfonts_font_tl \l_keys_choice_tl,
  font .generate_choices:V = \c_jcsfonts_clist,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\try}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { jcsfonts } { #1 }
  \tl_show:N \g_jcsfonts_font_tl
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\compare}{m}
 {
  \str_if_eq:nVTF { #1 } \g_jcsfonts_font_tl
   { \typeout{The ~ chosen ~ font ~ is ~ #1} }
   { \typeout{The ~ chosen ~ font ~ is ~ not ~ #1} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\try{font=lmodern} % works both in latex and xelatex
\compare{lmodern}
\compare{xyz}

\try{font=fontin}  % fails in latex

\stop
```

I believe that `.generate_choice:V` would be a useful addition to the tools. You can make a feature request through the mailing list.

---

An alternative version using the `.choices:nn` property (but with a variant as above).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \g_jcs_fonts_font_tl

\bool_if:nTF { \xetex_if_engine_p: || \luatex_if_engine_p: }
 { \clist_const:Nn \c_jcsfonts_clist { lmodern, fontin, constantia } }
 { \clist_const:Nn \c_jcsfonts_clist { lmodern, kpfonts } }

%%% The property .choices:Vn doesn't exist, so we create it
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__keys_choices_make:nn { V }
\cs_new_protected:cpn { \c__keys_props_root_tl .choices:Vn } #1
  { \__keys_choices_make:Vn #1 }

\keys_define:nn { jcsfonts }
 {
  font .choices:Vn = \c_jcsfonts_clist
   {
    \tl_gset:NV \g_jcsfonts_font_tl \l_keys_choice_tl
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\try}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { jcsfonts } { #1 }
  \tl_show:N \g_jcsfonts_font_tl
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\compare}{m}
 {
  \str_if_eq:nVTF { #1 } \g_jcsfonts_font_tl
   { \typeout{The ~ chosen ~ font ~ is ~ #1} }
   { \typeout{The ~ chosen ~ font ~ is ~ not ~ #1} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\try{font=lmodern} % works both in latex and xelatex
\compare{lmodern}
\compare{xyz}

\try{font=fontin}  % fails in latex

\stop
```

Comment: How do I get the conditional out of this? Would something like `\str_if_eq:VnTF \g_jcsfonts_font_tl {lmodern} {…} {…}` work?

Comment: @J.C.Salomon Yes. I'll add an example. I don't get any error except when I try with `pdflatex` because `fontin` is not a valid choice.

Comment: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.latex.latex3/3013